# emu8086 change case of the entered string and reverse it

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I am totally new in assembly language programming  and I am stuck with a problem in which I need to change case of the entered string plus reverse the string as well. I am using emu8086. I the following code I am either able to change case or reverse the  string. but I need to perform both the operations simultaneously.

```
.MODEL CASECHANGE

.DATA

        MSG1 DB  0DH,0AH, 'Enter string:$'
        MSG2 DB  0DH,0AH, 'String in reverse case:$'
        STR1 DB  255 DUP(?)


.CODE    

START:

          MOV AX,@DATA
          MOV DS,AX 


          LEA DX,MSG1
          MOV AH,09H
          INT 21H 

          LEA SI,STR1
          MOV AH,01H 
          jz offsets  
GET:

        INT 21H
        MOV BL,AL

        CMP AL,0DH
        JE  SET

        XOR AL,20H
        MOV [SI],AL
        INC SI

        JMP GET


SET:

      MOV AL,'$'
      MOV [SI],AL 



      LEA DX,MSG2
      MOV AH,09H
      INT 21H 


      LEA DX,STR1
      MOV AH,09H
      INT 21H 
      MOV AL,09H 

      JMP START
      JMP BACK  
      .EXIT
```

below code reverse the string and above code changes case and I need to join both codes to achieve desired output.

```
BACK:

        int 21h 
        MOV BL,AL
        cmp al,0dh

        jz exit  

        mov [si],al 
        inc si
        inc ch 
        jmp back



EXIT:      

        lea dx,MSG2
        mov ah,09h  
        int 21h 

cmp1:       

        mov al,[si]
        mov dl,al
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        dec si
        dec ch
        jnz cmp1
        mov ah,01ch
        int 21h


OFFSETS: 

        mov ch,01h
        mov si,offset STR1 

END START
```

These 2 set of codes are provided by my instructor so can only play with this code.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really read your massive wall of uncommented code.

To reverse a buffer in-place, get pointers to the first and last characters, then:

- Load the bytes into registers, then store the opposite registers back to the pointers.
- Increment the start pointer `si`, decrement the end pointer `di`.
- loop as long as start < end:  `cmp si, di  /  jb`

Downcasing can be done on a single character, so you can **do that on both bytes separately, when you have them in registers while you're swapping**.  Just check that it's between `'A'` and `'Z'`, then add 0x20.  (You unfortunately can't just `or al, 20H` unless you *know* that your character is already either a lower or uppercase letter, and not some other ASCII character).

Reversing to a new buffer is even easier.  Just go forwards in one array and backwards in the other, for `count` bytes.

If your target baseline CPU feature set included 386 instructions, you could have loaded 4B at a time and used `bswap` to reverse bytes 4 at a time.  Or with SSSE3, `pshufb` to reverse 16B at a time.

Comment: EMU8086 only emulates an 8086 and nothing more. Your final comment in general is correct, but in the OPs case it won't hold true. I know you did say **if**

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yup, that's why I said "if your target included", past tense, rather than "if your target includes".  Since the OP correctly tagged the question with 8086, and even mentioned emu8086, that was clear (which is a nice change from some questions).  Hmm, I should prob. have said "you could have loaded", to make the rest of the sentence match the past tense.