# Reverse case and order of a String using include 'emu8086.inc'

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, emu8086

In the following code I am able to reverse the string but I do not known how to add function in this code so as to get the following result:

> Input AbCDeF_XYz      Output: Zyx_fEdcBa

```
name "REVERSE"

include "emu8086.inc" 

      print "Enter a string:"
      MOV DX,11
      CALL get_string   
      printn
      MOV DI,0x0

ReadString:

      MOV AL,[ds+di]
      CMP AL,0x0
      JE Reverse
      INC DI
      PUSH AX
      JMP ReadString
Reverse:

      POP AX
      MOV AH,0xE
      INT 0x10
      CMP AL,0x0
      JNE Reverse

HLT

DEFINE_GET_STRING
END
```

Comment: search quickly turns up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578121/emu8086-change-case-of-the-entered-string-and-reverse-it, which has an answer.  You could just case-swap your characters before you push them, or after you pop them.  (test if they're in the ascii range, then xor with 0x20, because `'a' - 'A' = 0x20`.  So you just have to set or clear that bit to change between upper to lower case.)

Comment: I removed my previous comment, I see the reverse `case` now lol

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest these 3 solutions for your program:

- In your *push* loop you should also push the zero because now your *pop* loop will not correctly find a finishing zero!

  ```
    MOV DI,0x0
  ReadString:
    MOV AL,[ds+di]
    INC DI
    PUSH AX
    cmp al, 0
    jne ReadString
  Reverse:
  ```
- You can tackle the case swap by looking closely at the input string. It only has the underscore character **_** that poses a problem. You'll have to test for it and then bypass the case swap:

  ```
    MOV DI,0x0
  ReadString:
    MOV AL,[ds+di]
    INC DI
    cmp al,"_"
    je  NoSwap
    xor al,32  ;This toggles lowercase and uppercase
  NoSwap:
    PUSH AX
    cmp al, 0
    jne ReadString
  Reverse:
  ```
- In your current program you print the terminating zero. This is almost certainly not what you should do!

  ```
  Reverse:
    POP AX
    cmp al,0
    je  EndOfReverse
    MOV AH,0xE
    INT 0x10
    Jmp Reverse
  EndOfReverse:
    HLT
  ```

Comment: What about other symbols like @#$% etc? Wouldn't it be more prudent to test that the characters you want to change the case on fall within the valid ranges of alphabetic characters first?

Comment: @MichaelPetch That would certainly make for a more complete solution. I was really focussing on a quick solution for the example in the question.